# Trying to style the first tbody different than others without introducing another class

Tags: html, css

I have a table with multiple tbody's, each of which has a classed row, and I want it so that the classed row in the first tbody has style differences, but am unable to get tbody:first-child to work in any browser. Perhaps I am missing something, or maybe there is a workaround.

Ideally, I would like to provide the programmers with a single tbody section they can use as a template, but will otherwise have to add a class to the first tbody, making for an extra test in the programming.

The html is straightforward:

```
<tbody class="subGroup">
    <tr class="subGroupHeader">
        <th colspan="8">All Grades: Special Education</th>
        <td class="grid" colspan="2"><!-- contains AMO line --></td>
        <td><!-- right 100 --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>...</tr> <!-- several more rows of data -->
</tbody>
```

There are several tbody's per table. I want to style the th and td's within tr.subGroupHeader in the very first tbody differently than the rest. Just to illustrate, I want to add a border-top to the tr.subGroupHeader cells.

The tr.subGroupHeader will be styled with a border-top, such as:

```
table.databargraph.continued tr.subGroupHeader th, table.databargraph.continued  tr.subGroupHeader td {
    border-top: 6px solid red;
}
```

For the first tbody, I am trying:

```
table.databargraph.continued tbody:first-child tr.subGroupHeader th {
    border-top: 6px solid blue ;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in any browser (I've tested in Safari, Opera, Firefox, and PrinceXML, all on my Mac)

Curiously, the usually excellent Xyle Scope tool indicates that the blue border should be taking precedence, though it obviously is not. See the screenshot at http://s3.amazonaws.com/ember/kUD8DHrz06xowTBK3qpB2biPJrLWTZCP_o.png

This screenshot shows (top left) the American Indian th is selected, and (bottom right), shows (via black instead of gray text for the css declaration), that, indeed, the blue border should be given precedence. Yet the border is red.

I may be missing something fundamental, like pseudo-classes not working for tbodys at all... This really only needs to work in PrinceXML, and maybe Safari so I can see what I'm doing with webkit-based css tools.

Note I did try a selector like tr.subGroupHeader:first-child, but such tr's apparently consider the tbody the parent (as I would suspect), thus made every border blue.

Thanks...

Comment: You did take time to carefully escape all `<` to `&lt;` etc. in your source code, but not to read the formatting hints on the right side of the editor? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry folks, but I'm gonna answer my own question. But I do appreciate the help.

Instead of:

```
table.databargraph.continued tbody:first-child tr.subGroupHeader th {
    border-top: 6px solid blue ;
}
```

What I should have done was:

```
table.databargraph.continued > tbody:first-of-type tr.subGroupHeader th {
    border-top: 2px solid blue !important ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the tbody really the first child of the table? If there is any other element that is an earlier sibling (e.g. a thead?) than this will not work.

I've tried the following test code and it seems to work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        table tbody tr th {
            border-top: 6px solid red;
        }
        table tbody:first-child tr th {
            border-top: 6px solid blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When adding a thead element, this stops working, because there is no tbody that is the first child of the table. What does seem to work in that case (at least in Opera) is the following:

```
table thead + tbody tr th {
    border-top: 6px solid blue;
}
```

This selects all tbody that directly follow a thead.

Comment: Yes, there was a thead, and a selector using thead + tbody works for me, in (at least) Safari and PrinceXML so my issue is solved! Thanks!!!

Comment: `thead + tbody` will work as intended (the caption element should always be before thead, if it exists) and will have the broadest support from browsers, or you could also have used :first-of-type

Comment: btw, while I consider this question answered since it solved my immediate issue, but I'm not sure your logic is correct, since, if I understand correctly, that first-child refers to the first such element, that is, the thead shouldn't affect it any more than my col tags do.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, but as stated I don't need broad browser support in this case, just PrinceXML with webkit optional so I can check my work w/o constantly generating pdf's.